# Print an image in several sheets with real size

Tags: printing, scaling

I have a png with a specific dimension. In real life that would be 80cm * 30cm.

I looking for a way to print that in real life size in several sheets. It needs to be as precise as possible since its some clothing mould.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: What printer do you have?

Comment: I have a brother DCP-T300

Comment: @DavidPostill I am trying with Gimp unsuccessfully

Comment: Does the image encoding or metadata include its actual size or are you making a best guess?

Comment: No. The image itself states its size

Comment: I ended up using posterazor at the end